# Gable venting a bathroom fan and kitchen range hood

Tags: hvac, exhaust-fan, venting

I am planning on venting my bathroom fan and the range hood in my kitchen out the gable end of my house in separate runs.  The gable end is above a gable roof, so I am hoping for some recommendations on how far above the roof I need to install the vents.  The gable roof has two roof vents on them, but I'm not sure whether that matters.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The primary concern with any opening is bulk water infiltration. Sound practice is a minimum of 8" between the sill of the opening and the roof surface to provide for proper flashing and counterflashing. 12" is better.

So long as the duct layout and clearances are consistent with the manufacturer's recommendations, the installation should otherwise be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Mine was vented on the side of my house. Use metal duct instead if the cheap slinky type. Make sure you attach duct with screws and foil tape. Never vent out of gable vents, as these are intended to draw fresh air in while the roof vents draw moist air out. Good luck!